# how to delete quotation marks from a string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have this string in my project:

```
x = 'a124cd5f'
```

I’ve split it as below:

```
x1 = regexp(x, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', 2), 'match')
```

The answer will be:

```
x1 = ‘a1’ ‘24’ ‘cd’ ‘5f’
```

but i want the answer to be like this one:

```
x1 = a1  24  cd  5f
```

how may i do that?

Comment: the output can't be x1= a1 24 cd 5f, because it's a string. But it could be x1='a1 24 cd 5f'. Would that be okay?

Comment: do you want to parse hexadecimal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, you can't achieve an output like `x1=a1 24 cd 5f`, because that is not a string. It is possible, however, to achieve an output like `x1='a1 24 cd 5f'`. You could do it like this:

```
x2=cellfun(@(y) [y,' '],x1,'UniformOutput',0) % add a space between the different characters
x3=[x2{:}] % merge the different strings into one string.
```